# How to stop the width of an image from stretching inside a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an html form that takes input from a user and `php` code that takes the `input` from a specified folder. It then retrieves every image in that folder and displays it in a slideshow.

The problem is that the width of the image stretches and makes it look terrible. I tried the object-fit tactic among other tactics I found online but none of them seem to work.

**How do I maintain the aspect ratio of the images inside the cycle-slideshow?**

```
<html>
<head>
<style = "text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

<?php

$images = array();
$directory = 'images '.$_POST["name"];   

if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

elseif (preg_match("/\.gif$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

}

shuffle($images);

closedir($handle);

}

?>

<div class="cycle-slideshow">

<?php

for($i= 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

  foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;   
            echo '<img src="' . $path . '" class="displayed" 
   height= "512px"
   object-fit= "contain"
   width = "75%"


   display: "block"
   margin: "auto"
    border= "3px solid #73AD21" />';  
        }
    }  



}

?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try removing `width="75%"` - as it has the `height` it ought to scale properly

Comment: with that approach the image did fit inside the div but the size of the div also changed. i want the div(cycle-slideshow) to stay constant while the images inside it to fit accordingly.

Comment: The best thing would be to remove ALL inline styles and concentrate on using external CSS to govern the sizes - perhaps a flex-box approach?! As nobody but you knows what styles are applied to which elements you cannot expect a definitive solution.

Comment: i tried with the external css as well. couldn't get anywhere. here's my source code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rTLLj3XcCYwknG7n21Lm0Hrbrb6S2prq/view

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `width = "75%` because you already have height initialized. You can also add **padding** to the images in your CSS file. Note: For using padding you should actually use `box-sizing: border-box`. By using `border-box` you actually add that padding within dimensions of of your box and preventing it to change widht or height of it.
I didn't test it but hope i understood you question.

Comment: this may sound silly but i wrote the box-sizing: border-box inside the "img src" part of the code as well as tried writing it in the css part as well. but both didn't work. i wrote it like this - .cycle-slideshow{ box-sizing: border-box }. is that correct? also apologies for a tacky comment.

Comment: Have you tried **object-fit: cover;** ? Or, if you can you can provide us pure html and css relevant code so we can see all the potential elements that causes that problem.